# ListView in SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'am trying to create a System Alert Windows that contain a listView. But I have some problems. I can see that there is items in the listview but I can not read the text and nothing happens if I click on the items. Let me add some pictures of the issue. [image]

[image]

As you see in the first picture no items is showing but when showing layout bounds we can see that there is 2 items in the list.

```
    ListView lw = new ListView(this);
    String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
    lw.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
    layout.addView(lw);
```

This is how I created the list.

## edit

I solved the visibility issue but I have still some issues with clicking on items in the list. The strange thing is that it works on a samsung galaxy note but not on any other device. This is my click logic.

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.v("head", "click");
        }
    });
```

Comment: the textcolor of android.R.id.text1 is white and it seems your background is white too. I advise you use a baseadapter or override your array adapter, changing the color of the textView if you do not want to use base adapter anyway.

Comment: Thanks CrowdStar I will test this but I have the same issue with a different list that I know do not have white text. But I will test and see if I can get any items to show.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do something like this:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray ) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        String text = stringArray [position];
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        return textView;
    }
});
```

Comment: That solved the view issue but not the second issue where it is not possible to click on the items. It should be said it works on a samsung galaxy note but not any other phone. I used your code and added this:         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("head", "click");
            }
        });

Comment: can i see some implementation from your code. I mean snippet

Comment: I added it to the original post.